# iOS 7 cut, copy, select all - text options colour

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uitextfield, uitextview

In iOS 7 when you select text in a UITextField you get the 'cut, copy etc.' options pop up above. In my app they show as black but the screen has a black background so they don't show up very well.

I can't see anything in storyboard or the docs for this so wonder if there's any way I can change their colour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible with the public API. Make sure to file a feature enhancement over at https://bugreport.apple.com.

In the meantime, take a look at this open source implementation: https://github.com/questbeat/QBPopupMenu

You could customize it to appear as you like. You could then catch the system menu about to appear by listening to `UIMenuControllerWillShowMenuNotification` notifications, hide it, and display the custom one instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Leo, QBPopupMenu looks good so I might look at that if no one else has any other solutions!

Answer (score -1):

Although the accepted answer is a good walkthrough of how UIPasteboard works, I figured I'd post the relevant snippet right here for everyone's convenience:

UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteboard.string = @"paste me somewhere";